# How can I display certain div only for the first 2 iterations of a jade each loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, pug

I want to print out a div only for the first 2 iterations of a jade for each loop. How can I do something in jade similar to

```
counter = 0

for each tab in tabs
  if (counter == 0)
    div.nav-header NAVIGATION
    counter++
  else if (counter == 1)
    div.nav-header MY GROUPS
    counter++
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look a the `case` block: http://jade-lang.com/reference/

```
- var counter = 0
each tab in tabs
  case counter
    when 0
      div.nav-header NAVIGATION
    when 1
      div.nav-header MY GROUPS
  - counter++
```

Of course `tabs` should be an Array variable you pass to the Jade Engine.

A cleaner alternative could just use array indices:

```
each tab, counter in tabs
  case counter
    when 0
      div.nav-header NAVIGATION
    when 1
      div.nav-header MY GROUPS
```

Or even shorter with an `if` block (but I would prefer the `case` one for readability

```
each tab, counter in tabs
  if counter === 0
    div.nav-header NAVIGATION
  if counter === 1
    div.nav-header MY GROUPS
```